# WT 8-1: Getting HTTP GET on resource 'http://training4-american-api-maryumsiddique.us-e2.cloudhub.io:80/flights' failed: not found (404)

Tags: anypoint-studio, mule4, anypoint-platform

I'm doing mule 4 training and currently I'm on WT 8-1. I followed all the steps as they told and when I run the project it deployed successfully. But when I call "http://localhost:8081/american" from postman it gives me the following error.

[image]

Although the status is Started on Runtime Manager as below.

[image]

In API Manager the status is Active as well.

[image]

And I cannot figure out what's the issue. Can anyone please tell me what should I do? 
Really appreciate the help

Comment: I do have same issue. Did you solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Likely your app deployed locally is not calling the right URL for the API deployed in CloudHub. Maybe the URL should be http://training4-...cloudhub.io/api/flights or something like it.